# Using two printers with different paper formats in parallel

Tags: gnome, printing, cups, printer, evince

I use one ordinary ink jet printer with A4 paper size and one thermo label printer with 4x6 inch paper format. I configured those standard paper format in each printer device's settings. Nevertheless, this setting seem to be ignored because every time I'm in the print dialogue, the defined paper format is the one I had chosen in the previous print job, no matter which printer it was. Because I use both printers literally alternating, I have to change the paper format for the particular printer for every print job which is very annoying. Instead I would expect the configured paper format of the particular printer to be used by default, so that I don't have to change it each and every time.

Additionally, I have to change the scaling for the label printer to 150% for every print job because this setting is not remembered too, but I assume this is worth another ticket/question.

My system is Ubuntu Linux 18.04. I print PDFs (with evince) and PNG images (with eog).

Comment: I would suggest printing directly via command line.  That way, you can send the settings every time as a copy-and-pasted text message, rather than changing it manually.  E.g., printing the `png` images using the GUI, but using `pdftops | psselect | lpr` to print the PDFs.

Comment: Interesting idea. However the bigger picture is this: I'm looking for an easy to use solution (read: GUI-only solution) so that also colleagues of mine can easily and failsafe print the files as described. A command line solution won't work for them. In addition the files to be printed are downloaded with a web browser and shouldn't need to be stored on disk (because it would be another additional step).